# How to localise the numbers in iOS?

Tags: ios, nslocalizedstring

I did following to localise the strings. I wrote the following in .strings file:

```
"Hello"="Hello";
```

and in french  , .strings file:

```
 "Hello"="bonjour";
```

and I change the label as :

```
  self.myLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Hello", nil);
```

I am succesfull upto here. I have two cases:

Consider the number 2.5, where in english system it is `2.5` and in french system it is `2,5`.

How can I localise the numbers?

Edit: I used the property NSLocale, but I am unable to format the resulted number into string.

Here is what I get after converting into string:

```
 NSString *localizedDecimalString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%f",distance];

 result is 7 324,253011  //which is ok
```

and I want to append km at the end, so I tried to convert it back into double:

```
  double newlyChangedNumber = [localizedDecimalString doubleValue];

result is 7.0  //I should get 7324253011 here
```

How I can get something like 7 324,25 km?

Comment: you forgot the ';' in french, it would probably lead to a crash

Comment: this is generally handled by the OS based on the user's device settings (language and region).

Comment: @simpleBob I edited my question.

Comment: @T_77 I edited my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "translate" numbers by using the locale.

For example to show a float you would do:

```
NSString *localizedString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%3.2f", myNumber];
```

This method will use the system's locale(the result of `[NSLocale currentLocale]`). To use a custom locale either use `initWithFormat:locale:` or the `initWithFormat:locale:arguments:` method.

For more info read [Formatting Data Using the Locale Settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingLocaleData/InternationalizingLocaleData.html).

**UPDATE** (adapted to the question's update)

to add `km` at the end, just edit the format string like this:

```
NSString *localizedDecimalString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%f km",distance];
```

By the way, `[localizedDecimalString doubleValue];` did not work because it expect a point (`.`) decimal separator and a coma thousands separator (`,`). Therefore, it just converted until it reached an unexpected character, in this case the space. So, from `7 324,253011` it only converted the `7`. It would have worked with the english version (`7,324.253011`). To convert localized numbers' strings back to double/float, you would have to use a `NSNumberFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

`NSNumberFormatter` handles this. Just set [the `locale` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSNumberFormatter/locale) appropriately.

See also the open-source [FormatterKit](https://github.com/mattt/FormatterKit), which can, for example, convert between "1st, 2nd, 3rd" and "1ère, 2ème, 3ème".